# PHP Psalm covariance on method parameter

Tags: psalm-php

I have a case in PHP psalm that can be represented by this snippet:
https://psalm.dev/r/c31997fed4

The `handleNode()` method does not care about the type of node used, it should only care about that it is a Node. I have not been able to find a combination of @template params to make this snippet pass the psalm validations. Someone who has any idea?

Setting `@param TaskNode|ProjectNode` is no option in the real-life scenario, then I would have to update 100+ methods all the time with new classes.

Comment: It seems it's a bug in the Psalm or it doesn't go so deep into the analysis.